# Trying to check user permission set from related object validation rule

Tags: lookup, validation, permissions, access, custom-permission

Submitter field in the object has lookup to the user object. I am trying to create validation rule where only user with a specific custom permission set can be assigned to submitter field. But cannot figure out how can I check permission set of the user. Any ideas please

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two similar terms. First is **`Permission Set`**, which you *cannot* check for in validation rules, and requires queries from `Apex`. The second term is **`Custom Permission`**, which is easy to check from `Validation Rule`, and simply needs to be added to a `Permission Set` somewhere (it can be at the `Profile` level).